# Many commands report "Input/output error"

Tags: pi-4

```
$ uname -a
Linux xxx 5.15.30-v8+ #1536 SMP PREEMPT Mon Mar 28 13:53:14 BST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
$ uptime
-bash: /usr/bin/uptime: Input/output error
$ free -h
-bash: /usr/bin/free: Input/output error
$ host
-bash: /usr/bin/host: Input/output error
```

It behaves the same under root.

```
$ dmesg | tail -n20
[90202.778071] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 57021752 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[90202.965622] mmc0: Card stuck being busy! __mmc_poll_for_busy
[90202.965638] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[90202.965656] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 57021752 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[90203.149770] mmc0: Card stuck being busy! __mmc_poll_for_busy
[90203.149789] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[90203.310021] mmc0: Card stuck being busy! __mmc_poll_for_busy
[90203.310037] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[90203.494032] mmc0: Card stuck being busy! __mmc_poll_for_busy
[90203.494050] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[90203.658034] mmc0: Card stuck being busy! __mmc_poll_for_busy
[90203.658051] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[90203.845614] mmc0: Card stuck being busy! __mmc_poll_for_busy
[90203.845625] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[90204.029626] mmc0: Card stuck being busy! __mmc_poll_for_busy
[90204.029636] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[90204.206033] mmc0: Card stuck being busy! __mmc_poll_for_busy
[90204.206048] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
[90204.374047] mmc0: Card stuck being busy! __mmc_poll_for_busy
[90204.374064] mmcblk0: recovery failed!
```

I think it's something related to the SD card, but if so, then it's pretty bad, because the card is only few months old. It seems reboot temporarily fixes it, but not for long. Any idea what is the cause, how to fix it (without buying new SD card which would most likely fail the same way)? Is it normal for RPi 4 to wear down an SD card this quickly, or is this some kind of bug in Linux?

Comment: Your SD Card is corrupt. Restore from your backup. I am still using 9 year old SD Cards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ordered a new SD card as suggested, but after observing the behaviour for some time I am reasonably sure it is related to room temperature. It started to happen with warmer days (room temp around 30°C), it is closely linked to IO and/or CPU stress (starting stuff in docker, streaming from encrypted drive, night backups to encrypted drive). Very rarely it survived a day. Now, after 3 colder days (room temp ~24-26°C) it still works without the need to restart. The RPi is cooled by a passive case, I might need to buy a case with active cooling or cool the passive case externally. I also should set up monitoring (something like Zabbix on other RPi).

tl;dr Most likely caused by overheating.

Answer (score 1):

The input/output error are almost certainly IO errors on the sd-card. It is not normal for an SD-card to wear down in a few months.

I would suggest that either your SD-card is a problem or your Pi is broken (and breaks the Sd card as a result). I've had both.

If your Pi is functioning correctly, a new SD card will be the solution. If your Pi is broken, it will probably destroy the new SD card too.